# como remover o none de dentro da lista

Tags: python

Eu tenho que fazer o joguinho "torre de hanoi", na qual eu preciso passar os dados que estão na torre de origem para a torre de destino, usando uma torre auxiliar. porem quando os dados chegam a torre de destino, dentro da lista aparece um 'none':

algoritmo:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__items = []

    @property
    def items(self):
        return self.__items

    def isempty(self):
        return len(self.__items) == 0

    def push(self, item):
        self.__items.insert(0,item)

    def pop(self):
        if not self.isempty():
            return self.__items.pop(0)
        else:
            return print('Não há nenhum item para desempilhar')


    def peek(self):
        if not self.isempty():
            return self.__items[0]
        else:
            return print('Não há nenhum item no topo')

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)



class TowerOfHanoi:
    def __init__(self):

        self.__orig = Stack()
        self.__aux = Stack()
        self.__dest = Stack()


    @property
    def orig(self):
        return self.__orig

    @property
    def aux(self):
        return self.__aux

    @property
    def dest(self):
        return self.__dest


    def insere(self, elemento):
        self.__orig.push(elemento)

    def movedisk(self, n, orig, dest):
        transfere(n, self.__orig, self.__aux,self.__dest)
        print(f'{n} foi do pino {orig} para o pino {dest}')

    def movetower(self, n, orig, aux, dest):

        if n >= 1:

            self.movetower(n - 1, orig, dest, aux)
            self.movedisk(n, orig, dest)
            self.movetower(n - 1, aux, orig, dest)

tower = TowerOfHanoi()


def transfere(n,orig, aux,dest):
    while not orig.isempty():
        if n>=1:
            transfere(n-1, orig, dest, aux)
            transfere(n-1, aux, orig, dest)
        dest.push(orig.pop())




p = Stack()

tower.insere(3)
tower.insere(2)
tower.insere(1)


print(f'Pilha de origem: {tower.orig.items}')

print(f'A pilha de origem está vazia?{tower.orig.isempty()} ')

print(f'A pilha de destino está vazia?{tower.dest.isempty()} ')

tower.movetower(len(tower.orig.items), "A", "B", "C")

print(f'A pilha de origem está vazia?{tower.orig.isempty()} ')

print(f'A pilha de destino está vazia?{tower.dest.isempty()} ')

print(f'item da pilha de destino: {tower.dest.items}')

print(f'item da pilha de origem:{tower.orig.items}')

print(f'topo dest: {tower.dest.peek()}')

print(f'Tamanho dest:{len(tower.dest.items)}')

print(f'Quant movimentos: {2**len(tower.dest.items)- 1} ')
```

Comment: Vi que em alguns lugares você fez `return print('...')`; o retorno da função `print` é `None`, então sempre que essa expressão é executada sua função também retornará `None`, o que pode justificar a existência desses valores na sua lista.

Answer (score 2):

Considere checar o que o Anderson falou no comentário, mas respondendo sua pergunta diretamente: `[x for x in lista if x is not None]`

```
>>> lista = [5, None, 3]
>>> lista = [x for x in lista if x is not None]
>>> lista
[5, 3]
```